# How do I evaluate a Groovy string within a script?

Tags: java, groovy, command-line-interface, groovyshell

I'm essentially trying to create a CLI with Groovy. I have a whole JavaFX GUI set up in Java and I want to be able to type in groovy script to run different functions inside a groovy script.

For example, say I have this script:

```
void meow() {
    println "walrus"
}
```

I want to be able to type in "meow();" and press enter and evaluate it using the script as a reference.

I've tried using

```
shell.evaluate(inputStr, "src/Server/Scripting/CommandLineScript.groovy");
```

but to no avail; it just comes up with the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: CommandLineScript.meow() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I can call other standard functions, such as:

```
shell.evaluate("println 'Hello World!';");
```

but I just can't run my own methods... How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me.

```
evaluate(new File("/Users/jellin/meow.groovy"))
```

I did change the meow.groovy file to execute the method within the file.

```
void meow() {
    println "walrus"
}

meow()
```

One issue is I don't see a way to pass a parameter to the calling script.

I have used the following before, you can pass parameters as part of the binding.

```
String script = "full path to the script"
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine() 
Binding binding = new Binding();
Object result = gse.run(script, binding)
```

Also, you might be able to simply reference the other scripts as classes and execute the run method on them.

There is also an AST transformation that can be used to have scripts extend a base script.

See here for more info

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/05/groovy-goodness-basescript-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time guys; after a little more searching (always after posting a question do I find the answer in research >,<), I found that you can set a base class for the GroovyShell...  I did it this way:

```
ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
loader.addClasspath("src/ScriptLoc/");
binding = new Binding();
CompilerConfiguration compConfig = new CompilerConfiguration();
compConfig.setScriptBaseClass("ScriptName");

shell = new GroovyShell(loader, binding, compConfig);
```

I thought there would be a way to do it, and there it is...  Now whenever I need to evaluate a script from the text box, I can just evaluate it and it evaluates it in the context of the base script.